# How to setup LMFit constraints

Tags: python, lmfit

I've tried to look at other SO answers, but they always have these complicated setups or equations that I can never wrap around my head around how LMFit handles constraints or how they should be setup.

https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html

Let's say you have 4 variables

```
pars = Parameters()
pars.add('A', value=5)
pars.add('B', value=5)
pars.add('C', value=5)
pars.add('D', value=5)
```

You want to put some constraint

```
A+B > C+D
```

The document example states to set some arbitrary variable with some min and max for the value you want. So in this case would it be something like this?

```
pars.add('delta', max=0)
pars.add('D', value=5,expr='delta+A+B-C')
```

The logic being per documentation

```
A+B > C+D
C+D-A-B < 0 
C+D-A-B = delta where delta < 0  
D < A+B-C
```

So the final setup

```
pars = Parameters()
pars.add('A', value=5)
pars.add('B', value=5)
pars.add('C', value=5)
pars.add('delta', max=0)
pars.add('D', value=5,expr='delta+A+B-C')
```

Just trying to see if I"m understanding this correctly. t